# Ways to halo map text over a varying background?

Tags: arcmap, cartography, illustrator

I am ambivalent with using a halo effect. I am currently working on a small scale map of Africa showing the different types of vegetation and there are some crowded areas.

In terms of consistency, if I am going to introduce a halo for labels, I should add this effect to all labels of the same type (e.g. countries). However, it does just not look so nice in areas with single backgrounds.

What is the best practice?

[image: Example]

Comment: First ask yourself, whether you really need to place labels on a small scale map. You say yourself, that it is crowded, so maybe you should decide to not to show some information, or at least show it by different means or on another map. Second, be consistent.

Comment: Although your example is a GIS one, your problem really is a graphic/user interface problem. You could ask in the Graphic Design SE site: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ . If there are some GIS-specific restrictions on what you can do, mention them in your question there.

Comment: Perhaps the question is opinion-based, and solutions may also be specific to the style of your map, but cartographers face this challenge frequently, and cartography solutions will be more relevant than general graphic design tips. Here is one tutorial on creating more subtle halos in QGIS and/or Inkscape: https://wanderingcartographer.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/buffering-or-haloing-text-over-complex-backgrounds-using-the-screen-blend-mode/. In this other tutorial, outer-glows are used as halo, with a mask to downplay them over light colors: https://somethingaboutmaps.wordpress.com/2016/10/03/

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a halo effect that matches the background color of the map, rather than white or black (or whatever the default may be). This way the text is clear and unobstructed, but it's not distracting to look at. Here is an admittedly ugly example.

This:
[image: Halo Example 2]

Instead of this:
[image: Halo Example 1]

Comment: That works very well on a map with a single background. I really appreciate your answer. Unfortunately, the vegetation changes frequently and I have to place most of the labels over more than one background.

Comment: I guess I could have a different halo colour for each letter covering a different background.